# Delete rows in Excel based on returned value in row cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet in Excel with values in some rows in column B that have been returned as zero (0) but still have a formula in the cell. I want to be able to delete just these rows using a macro.

Comment: Do you want all cells in Column B that contain formulas deleted or only cells whose formula returns 0?

Answer (score 0):

As a software tutor I'm surprised you did not already know how to do this (or is this question just a test?) However, the following code may help:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

but I would recommend that (i) you turn on macro recorder and create the macro for yourself and (ii) take extreme care with any macro not created by yourself - in particular one that contains 'Delete' in it!

Note this deletes `Row1` so maybe best to insert a row at the top first - also deletes rows where "0" is not derived from a formula.